# The ways to take friend id from html form - get or post method

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to create a friend request in php. I need to take friend id and i am not sure what is best way to do it. This is my html:

```
   <form action="includes/addfriend.inc.php?id=<?=$userid ?>"  method="post">
            <button type="submit" name="addfriend">ADD FRIEND</button>
    </form>
```

And i take ids in by this way:

```
$id1 = $_SESSION['id'];     //me
$id2 = $_GET['id'];         //friend
```

Previously i did it by invisible input in form and taking it by POST method:

```
<input name="userid" hidden value="<?= $userid ?>">
$id2 = $_GET['userid'];
```

Are there more ways to do this? Which one is the best in which situations?

Answer (score 0):

The second way of putting it in a hidden input would be preferred. Another way to do it would be using ajax.
this might help with using ajax
[sending valus to php with ajax](https://www.formget.com/form-submission-using-ajax-php-and-javascript/)